# Webdriver - Write to a String in text box

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get my program to write a string into a text box with for loop but I cant seem to do it.

I tried to do it with function and without, and i debugged it and still could not find the problem

HTML:

```
<textarea class="challengeTextArea" rows="4"></textarea>
```

What I tried (python):

```
challange = "Dear, dear! How queer it seems, Alice said to herself, Which way? Which way?, holding her hand in hand with Dinah, and saying Come up again, dear! I shall"
text_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//textarea[@class='challengeTextArea']")
for letter in challange:
    print(letter)
    text_box.send_keys(letter)
print("IM HERE")
```

I expect it to write into the text file, but when i print the letter in the for loop it just prints the first letter and it doesn't even write it..

If you could not find the problem please let me know and i will give more pieces from my code .

Comment: Did you try to send the whole string `text_box.send_keys(challange)`? Does *"I expect it to write into the text file"* means *"I expect it to write into the text area"*?

Comment: Yes I tried this, and it doesn’t even prints what after the writing part(I’M HERE), and yes

Comment: Can you share the URL you're trying to automate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`send_keys()`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains.send_keys) or [`send_keys_to_element()`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains.send_keys_to_element) to populate a `textarea`, i.e.:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
html_content = """
<html>
     <head></head>
     <body>
        <textarea class="challengeTextArea" rows="4"></textarea>
     </body>
</html>
"""
driver.get("data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + html_content)
challenge = "Dear, dear! How queer it seems, Alice said to herself, Which way? Which way?, holding her hand in hand with Dinah, and saying Come up again, dear! I shall"
text_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//textarea[@class='challengeTextArea']")
text_box.send_keys(challenge)
```

---

Output:

[image]